# std::stringstream doesn't set failbit with wrongly formatted integer

Tags: c++

Any way to make `std::stringstream` set failbit after reading wrongly formatted integer like "234ewegre567" into `int` variable?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str("234ewegre567");

    int var;
    ss >> var;

    if (!ss) {
        std::cout << "fail";
    } else {
        std::cout << var;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
fail
```

Real output:

```
234
```

Comment: Try reading a second time. I perfectly works well within it's defined scope here.

Comment: @dansalmin you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `operator>>` actually works. What you have presented is not a failure code. The operator will stop reading when it reaches the `e` character, leaving the remaining data in the stream for subsequent reads, returning just the `234` integer by itself. For what you are attempting, use `std::stoi()` or equivalent instead, and validate whether the entire string was consumed or not.

Answer (score 2):

No, because 234 is a correctly formatted integer. There's no requirement that integers be terminated with whitespace or end of file.